# 翻訳の誤り: チャットの更新日時

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳, 日本語

右 pane に表示されるチャットへのリンクの部分で，最終更新が古くなって，「昨日」などでなく日付で表示されるようになった時に，`m月 d` という表示になっています（多分 Feb 1 などがそのまま持ってこられたのだとおもいます）．`m月 d日` への修正が望ましいと思います．

[image: 2月 1、]

Answer (score 3):

日付の後にある読点も気になります。投稿の更新日時の表示形式と同じ、

```
m月d日 hh:mm
```

がよいかなと思います。表示例:

[image: あてはめてみた]

Comment: たしかにこちらのほうがよいとおもいます！

Comment: Tranisfex上で適用しましたが、適用するまでしばらく時間がかかります。

Comment: https://www.transifex.com/projects/p/stack-overflow-ja/translate/#ja/english/40284698 を微調整しました